# How to unit test a class with multiple boolean fields

Tags: java, junit4

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I'd like to unit test the following class (there's more to the class but I stripped it down to illustrate my question).

The class consists of multiple boolean fields that get assigned in the constructor.

When I'm unit testing how can I test the parameters are assigned to the correct class field e.g. ans1 -> mIsOption1Ans ?

For example if I assert that all the class fields are "true" this will not identify if another developer has accidentally swapped the assignment in the constructor and assigned a parameter to the wrong class field. I'd like to test that "ans1" always gets assigned to "mIsOption1Ans", etc, etc

```
public class MultipleChoiceQuizAnswer {
   private Boolean mIsOption1Ans,mIsOption2Ans,mIsOption3Ans,mIsOption4Ans;

   public QuizAnswer (Boolean ans1,Boolean ans2, Boolean ans3,Boolean ans4) {
         mIsOption1Ans = ans1;
         mIsOption2Ans = ans2;
         mIsOption3Ans = ans3;
         mIsOption4Ans = ans4;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can either use reflection to check the value of private fields. Or use accesors (getters)

Comment: Create and read, test each of them: ans1,2,3,4 = 1,0,0,0 => expected read: 1,0,0,0 , then 1,2,3,4 = 0,1,0,0 => expected 0,1,0,0 ... then 0010, then 0001. If all of those succeed you have tested that each ansn is asserted to the respective mIsOption and _only_ that.

Comment: Thanks Fildor great idea that's the problem I was trying to solve

Comment: Do you have getters for those fields?

Comment: Access to the private variables is not the issue. I was trying to test the correct assignment of the boolean parameters, Fildor's answer solved my problem. Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really obvious thing but if you really want to test it you can test for each situation where 1 boolean is `true` and rest are `false`.

So for example:

```
QuizAnswer firstTrue = QuizAnswer(true, false, false, false);
assertTrue(firstTrue.isFirstAnswer());
// Then for next:
QuizAnswer secondTrue = QuizAnswer(false, true, false, false);
assertTrue(secondTrue.isSecondAnswer());
// Etc. You could also check if all other answers are false
```

Answer (score 3):

Your fields are an internal state of the objects. You should only test the class' behavior to the outside world. The fields' values cause some external behavior of `QuizAnswer`, which should be tested. E.g. if you have a method that checks whether an option is the answer:

```
@Test
public void first_option_is_the_answer_when_ans1_flag_is_true() {
    QuizAnswer answer = new QuizAnswer(true, false, false, false);
    boolean firstOptionIsAnswer = answer.isNthOptionTheAnswer(1);
    assertTrue(firstOptionIsAnswer);
}
```

You may have a look at [JUnit's Parameterized](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) runner, because you may want to write data driven tests.